# Group By a column based on multiple other columns - Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hello beautiful people,

Could someone please help me with my below request, (noting that I am working with Power Query Editor). So I need it to be done using creating conditional columns in power query maybe?, please help.

I need to group users in a table based on a category with showing their count in multiple different fields, As per the below example:

[image]

I need results to be:

[image]

Muuuuuuuuch Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, try this

Click select period and name columns

Right click, unpivot other columns

Click select period, attribute and value columns

Right click, group ... new column name Count, operation Count rows

Click select attribute column. Transform ... pivot column...  values column Count, Advanced options, do not aggregate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Period", "Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Period", "Attribute", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Count", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Alternately,

Click select period and name columns

Right click, unpivot other columns

Right click name column and remove

Right click value column and duplicate

Click select attribute column .. Transform pivot column ... Values column:Values Copy

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Period", "Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Name"}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", "Value - Copy"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value - Copy", List.Count)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Neither one is going to put in a blank row for a combination that does not exist like Dec No.  Thats more complicated if required

Comment: did this work for you?